Help with layout automation
I am a newbie trying to use LaTeX to create a template for a journal. I need your advice/help to handle 2 scenarios.

The first page has a different layout compared to other pages. When abstract content flows to the second page, it should take the full width. If the abstract content is shorter, then the body content flows into the first page after abstract. The width of the body content is shorter compared to the second page.
I am not sure how to get this automatically done when setting it as a template.
Any help/directions would be really helpful.

AFAIK, the text width cannot be changed automatically in the middle of a paragraph, and probably the same applies to a breakable tcolorbox box.  I am afraid that you will need to make two boxes in the first case, and manually break the paragraph in the second. See the manual of flowfram and search  in particular the \framebreak command that could be useful for this particular case, but is not an automatic solution.

the journal may provide a LaTeX class you can use. if not, they probably won't accept a LaTeX submission. they may accept PDF, but it probably won't need to look like the published result and they probably will demand some other format if the article is accepted. (in fact, they may well not accept an initial submission which looks like the published result.)

if you are not actually trying to submit to the journal but just want something with this style, maybe look at changepage.

I am not trying to submit a paper. I am working on automating the layout and this scenario is one such that I have to automate. We currently use XSLFO for typesetting, but trying to see if LaTeX can be used instead
